# How to tell if pressed YES or NO in a confirm dialog with Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

the method remove is called either I click YES or NO.
How can I tell if NO is pressed ?

```
    <p:commandLink  actionListener="#{mybean.remove}" 
    ajax="false"
     >
    <p:confirm header="Confirm" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert"></p:confirm>       <h:graphicImage value="images/erasebig.png" />
    </p:commandLink>    


    <p:confirmDialog id="dialog" global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" message="Are you sure?">
 <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" 
  styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" 
    />
 <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-close" />
     </p:confirmDialog>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no"` on the no-button and mybean.remove() wont be called